# why below system call ouput is not redirect to a file ?

Tags: c++, string, file, system

hi i am using smbclient to connect remote server in my c++ code  and to find whether write permission is enable or not on the remote connected server i   redirect to a file called tempfile as below:

command is

**smbclient //server/folder -u user%pass --directory=subfolder -c 'put file.txt' >tempfile**

output of this command is

**putting file file.txt as \subfolder\tempfile.txt (2.0 kb/s) (average 2.0 kb/s)**

if string **"putting file"** is present in a redirected file **tempfile** i confirm it is **enable** else **not**.but tempfile is always empty not sure why?

Below is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#define SMBCLIENT "smbclient "
#define TEMPFILE "tempfile"
#define search  "putting file"
enum errcode
{
EMPTY,
internalError

}errCode;

void getUserCreditentail(std::string &username,std::string &password,std::string &server,std::string &folder,std::string &subfolder)
{
        std::cin>>server;
        std::cin>>folder;
        std::cin>>subfolder;
        std::cin>>username;
        std::cin>>password;

}

void MakeCommand(std::string &command,const std::string server,const std::string folder,const std::string subfolder,const std::string username,const std::string password)
{
        if(server.empty() ||folder.empty() || username.empty() ||  password.empty())
        {
                errCode=EMPTY;
                return;
        }

        command= SMBCLIENT +server +"/"+ folder + " " + "-U"+ " " + username + "%" + password + " " + "--directory=" + subfolder + " " + "-c" + " " + "'put  testfile.txt'" + " " + ">" + TEMPFILE;
}

bool executeCommand(const std::string command)
{

if(!command.empty())
        {
                if(system(command.c_str())<0)
                {
                        std::cout<<"system call fails"<<std::endl;
                        errCode=internalError;
                        return false;
                }

        }

return true;


}

bool checkWritePermission()
{

        std::ifstream fin(TEMPFILE);
        std::string line;

        if (fin.is_open())
        {
                std::string line;

                while(getline(fin,line))
                {
                        if (line.find(search, 0) != std::string::npos)
                        {
                                std::cout << "found: " << search << std::endl;
                                return true;
                        }

                }

        }

        return false;
}
int main()
{
        std::string command;
        std::string username,password;
        std::string server,folder,subfolder;
        getUserCreditentail(username,password,server,folder,subfolder);
        std::cout<<server<<" "<<folder<<" "<<username<<" "<<password<<""<<subfolder<<std::endl;
        MakeCommand(command,server,folder,subfolder,username,password);
        std::cout<<command<<std::endl;
        if(executeCommand(command))
        {
                if(checkWritePermission())
                        std::cout<<"Write permission is enable"<<std::endl;
                else
                        std::cout<<"write permission is disabled"<<std::endl;

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: please help me to understand why downvote?

Comment: Does the command work as you expect if you execute it in the terminal?

Comment: yes it works but it output is not redirected to file rather it is displayed on terminal.Not sure why

Comment: Then it probably prints on stderr and not on stdout, and you need to read about how to redirect stderr.

Comment: i notice when it fails then it is redirect to a file but when it is success it is not redirected

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks i read and applied how to redirect both stderr and stdout and its working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect  stderr and stdout to files using **2>&1**

Changes your command as below

```
command= SMBCLIENT +server +"/"+ folder + " " + "-U"+ " " + username + "%" + password + " " + "--directory=" + subfolder + " " + "-c" + " " + "'put  testfile.txt'" + " " + ">" + TEMPFILE + " " + "2>&1";
```

NOTE I HAVE ADDED **SPACE** AND **2>&1** AT END OF YOUR COMMAND.